# Reading MAC frame and feeding it to Wireshark

Tags: python, pcap

We have a device receiving 802.11p MAC frames from the air and feeding them to the serial port completely unchanged (no network layer headers) and we'd like to see them arranged in Wireshark, so we can have a sort of self made sniffer for this 802.11p protocol.

My approach (in linux with python) was, open the serial port, read the frames and write them to a named pipe which wireshark would be listening to. After a lot of searching I've found out that the format i have to write into that pipe has to be like the pcap files format. I've looked to some python modules that do pcap formatting (scapy, pcapy, dpkt), but i can't find any that gets a pure MAC frame and simply writes it to a file in the pcap format in a way that wireshark can read and without me having to do all the parsing. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

How about just creating a [tap device](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) and writing the frames to that?  Then you can sniff the `tap` device with `wireshark` just like any other device.  There's an example using a `tap` device in Python [here](https://gist.github.com/585369), and a longer tutorial (actually about `tun` devices) in C [here](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/).

NB: I haven't tested this, but the idea seems reasonable...

**UPDATE**: This seems to work.  It's based on the above gist, but
simply reads frame data from a file and writes it to the device:

```
import sys
import fcntl
import os
import struct
import subprocess

TUNSETIFF = 0x400454ca
TUNSETOWNER = TUNSETIFF + 2
IFF_TUN = 0x0001
IFF_TAP = 0x0002
IFF_NO_PI = 0x1000

# Open TUN device file.
tun = open('/dev/net/tun', 'r+b')
# Tell it we want a TUN device named lars0.
ifr = struct.pack('16sH', 'lars0', IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI)
fcntl.ioctl(tun, TUNSETIFF, ifr)
# Optionally, we want it be accessed by the normal user.
fcntl.ioctl(tun, TUNSETOWNER, 1000)

# Bring it up and assign addresses.
subprocess.check_call(['ifconfig', 'lars0', 'up'])

print 'waiting'
sys.stdin.readline()

# Read an IP packet been sent to this TUN device.
packet = list(open('/tmp/packet.raw').read())

# Write the reply packet into TUN device.
os.write(tun.fileno(), ''.join(packet))

print 'waiting'
sys.stdin.readline()
```